Facing Error while using langchain's document loader
I am making a project on using RAG and am making use of langchain for it.
Firstly, I am loading the data using Langchain's Document Loader.
And then creating a data-base using ChromaDB.
I have tried many workarounds but none of them are working:

Using pip install python-magic-bin==0.4.14
Installing Microsoft C++ 14.0.27

Here is the below code snippet:

    from langchain_community.document_loaders import DirectoryLoader
    from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
    from langchain.schema import Document
    from langchain_openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
    from langchain_community.vectorstores import Chroma
    import openai
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    import os
    import shutil

    load_dotenv()
    openai.api_key = os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY']
    
    CHROMA_PATH = "chroma"
    DATA_PATH = "data/books"
    
    
    def main():
        generate_data_store()
    
    
    def generate_data_store():
        documents = load_documents()
        chunks = split_text(documents)
        save_to_chroma(chunks)
    
    
    def load_documents():
        loader = DirectoryLoader(DATA_PATH, glob="*.md")
        documents = loader.load()
        return documents
    
    
    def split_text(documents: list[Document]):
        text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
            chunk_size=300,
            chunk_overlap=100,
            length_function=len,
            add_start_index=True,
        )
        chunks = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
        print(f"Split {len(documents)} documents into {len(chunks)} chunks.")
    
        document = chunks[10]
        print(document.page_content)
        print(document.metadata)
    
        return chunks
    
    
    def save_to_chroma(chunks: list[Document]):
        # Clear out the database first.
        if os.path.exists(CHROMA_PATH):
            shutil.rmtree(CHROMA_PATH)
    
        # Create a new DB from the documents.
        db = Chroma.from_documents(
            chunks, OpenAIEmbeddings(), persist_directory=CHROMA_PATH
        )
        db.persist()
        print(f"Saved {len(chunks)} chunks to {CHROMA_PATH}.")
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()

Error snippet attached below:

Any Help is Appreciated!

First of all i would try to reduce the Error to a minimum. Is IT the document loader or the vectore store? However i think langchain_community.vectorstores is the old import maybe that's the issue.
